# how to know if an asp.net treeview selected node is leaf in clientside

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I've asked a question about contextmenu of treeview nodes ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470952/create-contextmenu-for-treeview-node-in-asp-net)) and I give no answer
so now I want to ask related question: is there any way to know if selected node of treeview is leaf or not(in clientside),because I want to create 2 different contextmenues,one for leaf nodes and one for others but I don't know how to know if selected node is leaf(that make leaf's contextmenu shown), is there any way?

Comment: I'm sure there is.. Look at what a node looks like in the markup and see if the current node contains anything that looks like that.

Comment: I didn't find what I want in markup